# Specifying onClick event type with Typescript and React.Konva

Tags: reactjs, typescript, konvajs

I'm trying to get rid of my tslint error `Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety.` but I'm struggling to figure out what the correct type would be for the Event.

I'm working through the Lynda "[Building and Deploying a Full-Stack React Application](https://www.lynda.com/React-js-tutorials/Profile-page-records/558648/597685-4.html?autoplay=true)" while trying to convert it to Typescript.

Here are the specific lines that are causing the issue:

```
onClick={(event: any) => {
 makeMove(ownMark, event.target.index)
}}
```

I have tried to declare the event as a few different types, like `React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>`, plus a few other subtypes on HTMLElement, with no success as the target.index is not a property on any type I can come up with. I can see from the inspector that the currentTarget is Konva.Text and the index is set to `0` but not sure that helps me as I can't set the type to `Konva.Text`, which would make sense to me, but that doesn't work either.

[image: React Konva Event target Index]

Here is my full React functional component:

```
export const Squares = ({units, coordinates, gameState, win, gameOver, yourTurn, ownMark, move}: SquaresProps) => {
  let squares = coordinates.map( (position: number, index: number) => { 
    let makeMove = move
    let mark = gameState[index] !== 'z' ? gameState[index] : false
    let fill = 'black'

    // when someone wins you want the square to turn green
    if (win && win.includes(index)) {
      fill = 'lightGreen'
    }

    if (gameOver || !yourTurn || mark) {
      makeMove = () => console.log('nope!')
    }

    return (
      <Text
        key={index}
        x={position[0]}
        y={position[1]}
        fontSize={units}
        width={units}
        text={mark}
        fill={fill}
        fontFamily={'Helvetica'}
        aligh={'center'}
        onClick={(event: any) => {
          makeMove(ownMark, event.target.index)
        }}
      />
    )
  })

  return (
    <Layer>
      {squares}
    </Layer>
  )
}
```

Here are my `package.json` dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "konva": "^1.6.3",
    "material-ui": "^0.18.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-konva": "^1.1.3",
    "react-router": "~3.0.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

I *think* the index is being added by the Konva Layer class but I'm pretty new to the whole react ecosystem so still trying to wrap my brain around it all.

### UPDATE:

I was able use declaration merging suggestion by Tyler Sebastion to define the index on the target which silenced tslint. I'm not sure this is the best approach though as it feels a bit fragile to me.

Here is the additional interface code and updated onclick event:

```
interface KonvaTextEventTarget extends EventTarget {
  index: number
}

interface KonvaMouseEvent extends React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement> {
  target: KonvaTextEventTarget
}

...

return (
  <Text
    key={index}
    x={position[0]}
    y={position[1]}
    fontSize={units}
    width={units}
    text={mark}
    fill={fill}
    fontFamily={'Helvetica'}
    aligh={'center'}
    onClick={(event: KonvaMouseEvent) => {
      makeMove(ownMark, event.target.index)
    }}
  />
)
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As posted in my update above, a potential solution would be to use Declaration Merging as suggested by @Tyler-sebastion. I was able to define two additional interfaces and add the index property on the `EventTarget` in this way.

```
interface KonvaTextEventTarget extends EventTarget {
  index: number
}

interface KonvaMouseEvent extends React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement> {
  target: KonvaTextEventTarget
}
```

I then can declare the event as `KonvaMouseEvent` in my onclick MouseEventHandler function.

```
onClick={(event: KonvaMouseEvent) => {
          makeMove(ownMark, event.target.index)
}}
```

I'm still not 100% if this is the best approach as it feels a bit Kludgy and overly verbose just to get past the tslint error.

Answer (score 218):

You're probably out of luck without some hack-y workarounds

You could try

```
onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
 makeMove(ownMark, (event.target as any).index)
}}
```

I'm not sure how strict your linter is - that might shut it up just a little bit

I played around with it for a bit, and couldn't figure it out, but you can also look into writing your own augmented definitions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

edit: please use the implementation in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45106836/877279) it is *the proper way to solve this issue* (and also upvote him, while you're at it).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I was going to try and cast the target but never got around to trying. I'll definitely give that a shot although that definitely feels a bit of a workaround. 

I will definitely read up on the declaration merging as I haven't seen that before.

Comment: Lambdas are forbidden in JSX attributes due to their rendering performance impact

Comment: @AlexeySh. they're discouraged, yes. I copied from OP's code.

Comment: This could trivially be moved into a `React.useCallback` to save on the lambda

Comment: Why is the reply in your edit the proper way? What's wrong with your approach?

Answer (score 42):

React.MouseEvent works for me:

```
private onClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  let button = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can do like this

```
   onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HtmlInputElement> = (e) => {
     const button = e.target as HTML
}
```

Comment: Could you give more details on why this should solve the problem?

Answer (score 11):

You should be using event.currentTarget. React is mirroring the difference between currentTarget (element the event is attached to) and target (the element the event is currently happening on). Since this is a mouse event, type-wise the two could be different, even if  it doesn't make sense for a click.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5733
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Answer (score 11):

I think the correct type is

```
event:React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
```

Comment: Thank you! All of the other answers felt complex or weird, but this one is straight forward and works without issues for the click event!

Answer (score 8):

You can use IntelliSense (or equivalent) from your IDE/editor to determine the type. Temporarily place the event handler in-line with the HTML element then hover your cursor over the event. Eg.

```
<button onClick={(event => console.log(event))}>Click me</button>
```

Hovering over `event` in VSCode shows:

```
(parameter) event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
```

Comment: You learned me how to catch fish instead of addressed me to fish market, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the ReactKonvaCore.d.ts file:

```
onClick?(evt: Konva.KonvaEventObject<MouseEvent>): void;
```

So, I'd say your event type is `Konva.KonvaEventObject<MouseEvent>`

Comment: ReactKonvaCore.d.ts => can you post direct link

Comment: @Nelles Quick search turned up https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/blob/master/ReactKonvaCore.d.ts

Answer (score 1):

I think you may try. It works on me.

```
const handleClick = (event: SyntheticEvent) => {
    const target = event.target 
};

<Button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const Example = () => {

      const handleSubmission = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void => {
          event.preventDefault()
          .....
      }

      return <button onClick={handleSubmission}>Submit</button>
}
```

So the solution is `React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>`

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick={(event: Event) => {
    const { index } = event.target as unknown as { index: number }; 
    makeMove(ownMark, index);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, for working with DOM you can use **MouseEvent**.
It will be correct for @typescript-eslint. Example:

```
const onClickEverywhere = (e: MouseEvent) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log(e.target);
};

useEffect(() => {
  document.body.addEventListener('click', onClickEverywhere);
  return document.body.removeEventListener('click', onClickEverywhere);
}, []);
```