# TypeScript React, What is the correct type for getting the id of a div onClick?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can't find the correct type for the onClick event that will allow me to get the id of the div that was clicked.

```
  const setColor = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    const color = event.target.id;
//                             ^--- error Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)
    if (selected) selected.updateColor(color);
  };
```

The jsx is

```
<div id={'#C81B00'} onClick={setColor} className='inspector--color' style={{backgroundColor: '#C81B00'}}></div>
```

I also tried

```
<div id='#FA2200' onClick={setColor} className='inspector--color' style={{backgroundColor: '#FA2200'}}></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `currentTarget` as a workaround. `currentTarget.id` should work just fine.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5733

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59278654/5579073

Answer (score 1):

you could also type it like this:
(event: MouseEvent & {target: HTMLElement})